# FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates gets trigger to call onLocationChanged only after GPS is turned on

Tags: android, google-play-services, locationmanager

After spending lots and lots of hours of experimentation and after trying multiple combinations of calls and settings, I narrowed down to this:

Google Play services location APIs `FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` ideally should call `onLocationChanged` for specified time interval when any location service is turned on. However, the actual behavior is weired and is like this:

1. If all location services are turned off it never calls `onLocationChanged`....... Expected behavior
2. If only wifi/mobile network location service is turned on, it never calls `onLocationChanged`....... Unexpected behavior
3. If only GPS location service is turned on, it never calls `onLocationChanged` (even if we turn on wifi location service afterwards)....... Unexpected behavior
4. If GPS location service is turned on (after turning on first wifi/mobile location service), it calls `onLocationChanged` (and keeps calling even after we turn off GPS afterwards)....... Expected behavior
5. If wifi location service is turned on (after turning on first GPS location service), it never calls `onLocationChanged` ....... Unexpected behavior

In short: It calls `onLocationChanged` only after we turn on wifi first and then GPS. (However, GPS is no longer needed afterwards for it to call `onLocationChanged`)

Here is my code:

```
void ConnectToLocationApi()
{
    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    if(m_GoogleApiClient == null)
    {
        // Initialize Google Api client
        m_GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Connect to Google play service location api
        m_GoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}


@Override
public synchronized void onConnected(Bundle bundle) // Called when m_GoogleApiClient.connect() succeeds
{
    Log.d(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");

    try
    {
        LocationRequest locationRequest;

        // Initialize location request
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Start receiving location updates
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(m_GoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

        // Get location details of last available location (if any)
        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(m_GoogleApiClient);

        if (lastLocation != null)
        {
            ShowToast(this, "Last location received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Log.i(TAG, "In onConnected. Latitude:" + m_Location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude: " + m_Location.getLongitude());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "getLastLocation returned NULL value");
        }
    }
    catch (SecurityException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "getLastLocation failed because of security exception (permission issue?)");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) // Called when m_GoogleApiClient.connect fails
{
    ShowToast(this, "GoogleApiClient connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    m_GoogleApiClient = null;
    Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) // Called when m_GoogleApiClient.connect suspended
{
    Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}

@Override
public synchronized void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    ShowToast(this, "Location update received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    Log.i(TAG, "In location changed. Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
}
```

Note: I preferred Google Play services location APIs over the Android framework location APIs after I read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html). Any clue please? I am badly stuck.

Comment: Can you describe how you did the wifi/mobile location check (physical device moving x meters, mock location provider) and physical device(s) used?

Comment: Physical device used. However, movement is not necessary when I ask for periodic updates. It keeps invoking callback every `LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS/1000` seconds.

Comment: What values are you using for LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS and FASTEST_LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS

Comment: 5 seconds and 1 second. (`LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 5000`and `FASTEST_LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000`) And it works perfect in case #4 in the question.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851816/android-location-update-frequency

Comment: I have just wasted about 2 days of my life. Thanks for the comments. The question now is how do we write quality location based apps? Google get it sorted

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in listening.
If i started GoogleApi services before i get premission for location and gps on, then OnLocationChanged never called. So
In OnPermissionGrantedResult and in reciver for android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED i am restarting GoogleApiServices and starting to recive location events